# script 'engine7.php' not found or unable to stat

Tags: php, apache2

Some application on my Centos Server can't running well.

I've error on /var/log/httpd/error.log and then i got error message like bellow :

```
script 'engine7.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://fdc.xchecker.net/2013/http/engine7.php
```

I try to find engine7.php with locate command but i can't find engine7.php anywhere.

Could anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Well, you need to find source code of this application (if it was downloaded from somewhere) and get engine7.php from there.

Comment: Also, check out this question: [robot-hammering-apache2](http://serverfault.com/questions/414001/robot-hammering-apache2)

Comment: Seriously ? Can't you just use a search command and search for the file and move it in the right location ?

Comment: I 've search using 'locate' command, but stil can't find engine7.php

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue may be related to this one:

https://serverfault.com/questions/414001/robot-hammering-apache2

If that is the case, then it is not that you have a script running on your server. Instead, some kind of robot or proxy tester is trying to access a page on your website that does not exist.

Comment: Remember to explain the link so that your answer is valid even if the link is dead.